# How to represent this data for k means clustering

Tags: r, k-means

I have groups of users and their associated words. This is how I have grouped them :

I have associated each word with a number and if the user does not have any of these words associated I give a value 0 :

google : 1
stackoverflow : 2
math : 3
programming : 4
noword : 0

To run a k-means algorithm I associate the words like so :

```
username  google stackoverflow math programming
user1        1        0          3      0
user2        1        2          0      4
user3        0        2          3      0
user4        1        1          0      4
```

Is this a correct implementation of how to cluster each user and check how close they are to each other based on what words they have configured ?

I'm basing this implementation on : http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/K-Means

In particular this section : 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that your data can be constructed as binary. For instance, user 1 either has an association with **stackoverflow** or does not (i.e., a binary value). Hence, you should munge your data to this format:

```
username  google stackoverflow math programming
user1        1        0          1      0
user2        1        1          0      1
user3        0        1          1      0
user4        1        1          0      1
```

I would advise against K-means for your data because the concept of cluster centroids is problematic for binary data. For more details, see the first few paragraphs of [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21477401).

However, you can still compute the similarity between any two users using an appropriate method, such as the [Jaccard index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) because each user's word associations can be written as a binary string (e.g., user1 has `1010`). You could then construct a [similarity matrix](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/Dissimilarity_Matrix_Calculation) between all pairs of users and cluster them with a method such as [hierarchical clustering](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/Hierarchical_Clustering).

Alternatively, you could use something like [Proximus in R](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/Proximus).

Comment: just looking at your answer again, why is it problematic to represent my data as I have in question ? ie : assigning a unique numerical value to each word

Comment: The short answer is because of your goal of clustering, which will find those users that are similar in terms of distance. Distance does not make sense in how you were trying to use it. In other words, your original construction implies the features are nominal, but most clustering methods, such as K-means, implicitly assume the data are on a [ratio scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Ratio_scale).